Network policy - Kubernetes
The back-end is deployed in K8s and the Front End is a mobile application. I would like to isolate the communication between the Back-end and the Front-end.
And after some research, I discovered that a network policy would be a solution. I want to configure a network policy from the Kubernetes node to a mobile application.
What type of network policy should I use?
Do you have a better approach?
I tried the below approach and I don't want to collect all IP addresses to exclude
 - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24

